# Hazelcast embedded and Split-Brain Syndrome

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, distributed

I have Hazelcast in embedded mode and when i simulate network problems, i get inconsistent data between nodes. What can i do? Any advice?

```
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:instance-name>hazelcast-instance</hz:instance-name>
        <hz:group name="${machineId}"/> 
        <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="true" multicast-group="224.2.2.3" multicast-port="54327"/>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

Comment: What type of datastructure ? `IMap` ? `Lock` ?   And what version of Hazelcast (3.12.1 ?)

Comment: I have changed HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory to HazelcastCacheRegionFactory and set LatestUpdateMergePolicy, and now it works.